# php soap request and response with authentication

Tags: php, web-services, soap

This is a soap request and response.

I am getting the below error message but I don't understand what is wrong:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 570). ---> The string '2016-02-24 11:14:15.638276' is not a valid AllXsd value. in test.php:19 Stack trace: #0 test.php(19): SoapClient->__call('CreateVehicleIn...', Array) #1 test.php(19): SoapClient->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy(Array) #2 {main} thrown in test.php on line 19

This is a web application to issue insurance policy, at that time we want to connect to the web server.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <SoapHeaderIn xmlns="http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx">
      <userName>string</userName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </SoapHeaderIn>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy xmlns="http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx">
      <lngInsuranceCompanyCode>long</lngInsuranceCompanyCode>
      <intInsuranceKindCode>int</intInsuranceKindCode>
      <lngTcf>long</lngTcf>
      <strPolicyNo>string</strPolicyNo>
      <dtExpiryDate>dateTime</dtExpiryDate>
      <dtStartDate>dateTime</dtStartDate>
      <strChassisNo>string</strChassisNo>
      <strRemarks>string</strRemarks>
      <strUserCreated>string</strUserCreated>
    </CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <SoapHeaderOut xmlns="http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx">
      <intResponseCode>int</intResponseCode>
      <strArMsg>string</strArMsg>
      <strEnMsg>string</strEnMsg>
    </SoapHeaderOut>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateVehicleInsurancePolicyResponse xmlns="http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx">
      <CreateVehicleInsurancePolicyResult>
        <intFLSCode>int</intFLSCode>
        <strFlsDescAr>string</strFlsDescAr>
        <strFlsDescEn>string</strFlsDescEn>
        <lngSerial>long</lngSerial>
        <lngTrafficID>long</lngTrafficID>
      </CreateVehicleInsurancePolicyResult>
    </CreateVehicleInsurancePolicyResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Code:

```
<?php
class SOAPStruct
{
    function __construct($user, $pass) 
    {
        $this->Username = $user;
        $this->Password = $pass;
    }
}

$service = new SoapClient("https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?wsdl");

$auth = new SOAPStruct("****","*****");

$header = new SoapHeader("http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx","SoapHeaderIn",$auth,false); 

$service->__setSoapHeaders($header);   

$response = $service->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy(array('lngInsuranceCompanyCode' => '71','intInsuranceKindCode'=>'123','lngTcf'=>'2563214','strPolicyNo'=>'10002356','dtExpiryDate'=>'2016-02-24 11:14:15.638276','dtStartDate'=>'2015-03-25 11:14:15.638276','strChassisNo'=>'WVWZZZ3AZRE161907','strRemarks'=>'demo','strUserCreated'=>'demo'));
var_dump($response);
?>
```

I am trying to access this web service but i am getting error.

I am new to SOAP requests so I am stuck.

Comment: **welcome back again and welcome again in stackoverflow with new account.** :) didn't you try what I have given you?

Comment: Please tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 570). ---> The string '2016-02-24 11:14:15.638276' is not a valid AllXsd value. in test.php:19 Stack trace: #0 test.php(19): SoapClient->__call('CreateVehicleIn...', Array) #1 test.php(19): SoapClient->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy(Array) #2 {main} thrown in test.php on line 19

Comment: Now i change dateTime and error like "object(stdClass)#4 (0) { }"